# Login as root on startup login prompt

Tags: 12.04, root

I need to use the root account - i.e. log on as root from the start.

I'm not interested in sudo or getting temporary root privileges.

And with the greatest of respect- please no warnings about root or it not being best practice! I've seen a few threads on this and the focus seems to be more about not using it rather than a clear set of instructions to enable the root account. Every thing suggested does not work.

I just need to be presented with a root account when I boot up my machine.

I would therefore be grateful for a concise set of instructions without the string of dire warnings. It would be great to pin such a guide as there seems to be so  many versions.

Thank you

Comment: This very much looks like an X-Y-problem. Please tell us **why** you need exactly this approach. Usually `sudo - i` accomplishes everything you should need.

Answer (score 1):

Root user already exist in PC but password is not setup.

Just you need to do

> sudo passwd root

that's it.

then you can do as normal logs as user.